# Spring AOP - Multiple Interceptors not working together

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I want to apply advice to a method `helloWorld`. I would like to throttle calls exceeding 'x' TPS and retry those calls.

So I have 2 interceptors -

1. Throttle Interceptor, which throttles call rate exceeds 'x'
2. Retry Interceptor, which retries if call is throttled.

> The issue is that when I combine the 2 Interceptors the Throttling
>   interceptor does not seem work even if I provide the Rate as 0, that is the helloWorld methos gets executed.
>
> If I only
>   use the Throttling Interceptor it works fine.

My `Spring Configuration` is like this.

```
<bean id="retryPolicy" class="xyz.RetryPolicyFactoryBean">
    <property name="backoffCoefficient"><value>2</value></property>
    <property name="multiplierMillis"><value>100</value></property>
    <property name="maxDelayMillis"><value>2000</value></property>
    <property name="maxAttempts"><value>2</value></property>
    <property name="expirationDurationMillis"><value>60000</value></property>

<bean id="retryInterceptor" class="xyz.RetryInterceptor">
<constructor-arg index="0"><ref bean="retryPolicy"/></constructor-arg> 
</bean>

<bean id="throttlingInterceptor" class="xyz.ThrottlingInterceptor">
    <constructor-arg index="0"><value>key</value></constructor-arg> 
</bean>

<bean id="helloWorld" class="xyz.helloWorld" />

<bean id="helloWorldProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target" ref="helloWorld" />
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>retryInterceptor</value>
            <value>throttlingInterceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

`Throttling Interceptor` is like this:

```
@Override
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
    if (isDecorated(methodInvocation)) {
        if (throttler.isThrottled(key)) {

            throw new ThrottlingException("Call throttled.");
        }
    }
    return methodInvocation.proceed();
}
```

My `retry interceptor` is like this:

```
public class RetryInterceptor extends RetryAdvice {

public RetryInterceptor(RetryPolicy retryPolicy) {
    super(retryPolicy);
}

@Override
public Object invoke(final MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
    return super.invoke(methodInvocation);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the use of extending `RetryAdvice`? And why are you using old ways of applying AOP? and what is `RetryAdvice`?

Comment: @M.Deinum I am new to Spring AOP so would appreciate if you could direct me to the standard way of using AOP. Retry Advice is a class which applies the retry policy. It has an invoke() method which just applies the RetryPolicy provided to it and calls methodInvocation.proceed(); Is there a better way to use retries?

Comment: But why are you extending it? Your extension doesn't add anything... The override and the constructor don't make sense... But you want to use `<aop:config />` to specify your AOP you don't want to manually add `ProxyFactoryBean`s for each AOP bean. That is error prone and exceptions are going to be made.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am going through the documentation of <aop:config>. A quick question, what advice fits this use case? before or around? Also in this example, when the retry advice is applied does the method call go through the throttling advice again?

Comment: That depends on the order of the interceptors...

Answer (score 0):

I followed the newer approach using AspectJ Annotations & got it working (atleast now the interceptors are being called).

Annotate the Class which contains the advice with `@Aspect`

Here is my Throttle Advice:

```
@Before(pointcut="execution(* com.company.xyz.method())")
public void invoke() throws ThrottlingException {
    if (throttler.isThrottled(throttleKey)) {
        throw new ThrottlingException("Call Throttled");
    }
}
```

My retry Interceptor:

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut="execution(* com.company.xyz.method())", throwing="exception")
public Object invoke(JoinPoint jp, ThrottlingException exception) throws Throwable {
return RetryingCallable.newRetryingCallable(new Callable<Object>() {

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
            MethodSignature  signature = (MethodSignature) p.getSignature();
            Method method = signature.getMethod();
            return method.invoke(jp.getThis(), (Object[]) null);
    }

}, retryPolicy).call();
```

}

Relevant Spring Config

```
<bean id="retryInterceptor" class="com.company.xyz.RetryInterceptor">
<constructor-arg index="0"><ref bean="retryPolicy"/></constructor-arg> 
</bean>


<bean id="throttlingInterceptor" class="com.company.xyz.ThrottlingInterceptor">
<constructor-arg><value>throttleKey</value></constructor-arg> 
</bean>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

Another point to take care of is the [Order](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering) in which the Interceptors are called. Use @Order Annotation to ensure the order.